# Multiline named match with JavaScript regex not matching regex101

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a named match regex expression in JavaScript which captures build information from a multiline string. It tests fine in regex101 but fails to match correctly in JavaScript in a single pass of exec.

When I try the the following regex in JavaScript all that is matched is the first match, i.e. .  Everything else shows up as `undefined`.

When I test the following in regex101.com

```
/(BuildTimestamp:)(?<timestamp>.*)|(VersionCode:)(?<major>.*)|(VersionName:)(?<minor>.*)/gm
```

```
BuildTimestamp:30-May-2023 14:25\r\n
VersionCode:6\r\n
VersionName:.0.5\r\n
```

I get the following matches:

```
timestamp: 30-May-2023 14:25
major: 6
minor: .0.5
```

In JavaScript I'm doing the following:

```
const regex = /(BuildTimestamp:)(?<timestamp>.*)|(VersionCode:)(?<major>.*)|(VersionName:)(?<minor>.*)/gm;

const match = regex.exec(contents);
```

If I put the `exec` in a loop I'm able to capture each named match in turn when `exec` is called. I'm hoping that there is a way to modify the regex query to capture all of them in one go.

The results of the first match are as follows
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should be self-explanatory. I've just added `\r?\n` to the regex then used the `groups` property of the return value.

```js
const contents =
`BuildTimestamp:30-May-2023 14:25
VersionCode:6
VersionName:.0.5`;

const regex = /BuildTimestamp:(?<timestamp>.*)\r?\nVersionCode:(?<major>.*)\r?\nVersionName:(?<minor>.*)/;

const match = regex.exec(contents);

//const { timestamp, major, minor } = match.groups;

console.log(match?.groups);
```

Comment: This regex produced the easiest to use and cleanest results.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`String.prototype.matchAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll):

```js
const regex = /(BuildTimestamp:)(?<timestamp>.*)|(VersionCode:)(?<major>.*)|(VersionName:)(?<minor>.*)/gm

const result = `BuildTimestamp:30-May-2023 14:25\r\n
VersionCode:6\r\n
VersionName:.0.5\r\n`.matchAll(regex);

console.log([...result]);
```

Or you could modify the regular expression to match it all in one go. You may wish to adjust the regular expression further if you don't want to capture the `\r\n` sequences:

```js
const regex = /(BuildTimestamp:)(?<timestamp>.*)(VersionCode:)(?<major>.*)(VersionName:)(?<minor>.*)/s

const result = regex.exec(`BuildTimestamp:30-May-2023 14:25\r\n
VersionCode:6\r\n
VersionName:.0.5\r\n`);

console.log(result);
```